# Why are there two identical headwords in an index where there should only be one?

Tags: spacing, indexing

In an index generated by Latex there are the two headwords: `abhainn, 52` and `abhainn, 53`. But there should only be one, `abhainn 52, 53`.

Both of the instances of `abhainn` are marked identically in the original file as `\emph{abhainn}\index{abhainn@\textbf{abhainn}}`, so they shouldn't be treated as different in the indexing of them.

But in the `.idx` and `.idn` files they are different: they are as follows: in .idn, `\item \textbf {abhainn}, 52` (with the gap as indicated between `\textbf` and `{abhainn}`) but `\item \textbf{abhainn}, 53` (without this spacing).

The irregular spacing occurs also in the `.idx` entry  `\indexentry {abhainn@\textbf {abhainn}}{52}`, but not in `.idx` entry `\indexentry{abhainn@\textbf{abhainn}}{53}`.

Why is there a difference of spacing in these entries, even though they are marked identically as `\emph{abhainn}\index{abhainn@\textbf{abhainn}}`
in the original file? This spacing seems to be introduced as a result of the creation of the `.idx` and `.idn` files, as it is not in the original file, but is it the reason why there are two identical headwords in the index where there should only be one?

Answer (score 2):

This happens if you "hide" one of the index commands inside some other command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
blub \index{abhainn@\textbf{abhainn}} 
\newcommand\mytext{\index{abhainn@\textbf{abhainn}}}\mytext 

\printindex
\end{document}
```